# Making Cabal Aware of External TemplateHaskell Dependencies

Tags: haskell, cabal, template-haskell

To embed some static files in a build, I'm using: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/file-embed-0.0.10.1/docs/Data-FileEmbed.html

It allows you to do:

**MyFile.hs**

```
myFile :: Data.ByteString.ByteString
myFile = $(embedFile "something/external.txt")
```

To embed files into the produced binary.

However, one irksome thing is that cabal doesn't know that a file using `embedFile` depends on the file it loads (and therefore changes to `something/external.txt` don't cause `MyFile` to be re-built on build).

Is there any way to tell cabal about this dependency? The only solution I have now is to just `touch` the Haskell file to cause it to be recompiled, but this is tedious.

Comment: `data-files` or `data-directory` in your `package.cabal`?

Comment: see https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html#pkg-field-data-files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[addDependentFile](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell-2.13.0.0/docs/Language-Haskell-TH-Syntax.html#v:addDependentFile) is part of template Haskell.  It tells ghc to use that file in dependency calculations - cabal isn't even needed.

`embedFile` should be calling that.  The fact that it isn't makes me suspicious about the library.  Still, you can create a helper that looks something like this:

```
embed :: FilePath -> Q Exp
embed p = addDependentFile p >> embedFile p
```

Just mind TH's staging restrictions, and put that in a file that doesn't use it.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I was looking for. That's so smart that they thought ahead to include that! Thank you so much!

Comment: Doesn’t seem to work for me under Cabal 3.2. People on IRC say that Cabal is not aware of `addDependentFile`.